# "(1) near ";": syntax error" and "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" android java

Tags: java, android, exception, syntax, syntax-error

As the title suggests, have had a few errors based on source code. Attempted to find a combination of ;: within the file however was not found.

```
01-14 18:49:12.384: E/SQLiteLog(17346): (1) near ";": syntax error
01-14 18:49:12.384: E/CurrentItems(17346): Could not create or open the database
01-14 18:49:12.474: W/dalvikvm(17346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c83498)
01-14 18:49:12.474: E/test(17346): Exception
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foodcalculator/com.example.foodcalculator.CurrentItems}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at com.example.foodcalculator.CurrentItems.onCreate(CurrentItems.java:73)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
01-14 18:49:12.484: E/AndroidRuntime(17346):    ... 11 more
```

Main class

```
package com.example.foodcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Homepage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
        final Button editInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editItem);
        final Button currentInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentItems);
        final Button settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddItem.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        currentInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CurrentItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        editInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    static final class ProductData {
        String barcode;
        String title;
        Double quantity;
    }
}
```

Current Items class

```
package com.example.foodcalculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CurrentItems extends ListActivity {

    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "foodcalculator.db";
    private final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "products";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase foodDB = null;

        try {
            foodDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE,
                    null);

            foodDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + PRODUCT_TABLE
                    + " (barcode String, format String,"
                    + " title String, price Double;");

            foodDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + PRODUCT_TABLE
                    + " Values ('564565645665','Beans',1.5);");

            Cursor c = foodDB.rawQuery("SELECT FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE, null);

            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
                        Double quantity = c.getDouble(c
                                .getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
                        results.add("" + title + ",Quantity: " + quantity);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or open the database");
        } finally {
            if (foodDB != null)
                foodDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE);
            foodDB.close();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_inventory);

        final Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        final Button editInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editItemCurrent);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Scanner.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        editInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your SQL syntax.

Comment: What is line 73 CurrentItems.java

Comment: line 73,     scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: `scanButton` is null then -- are you sure `R.id.addButton` exists in the layout?

Comment: @tagz2712 post `current_inventory.xml`. i suspect more errors

Comment: have managed to solve the null pointer issue however still have the near ";": syntax error issue

Comment: @tagz2712 i think its bcoz your sql statement

Comment: @tagz2712 `price Double;` is the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your SQL code is in `CurrentItems`, here:

```
+ " title String, price Double;");
```

You're missing an end parenthesis after `Double`. It should read as follows:

```
+ " title String, price Double);");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line 73, scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

scanButton is null.

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id `addButton` in `current_inventory.xml` which is the current inflated layout. If it does not find the view then you end up with `NullPointerException`.

I think the syntax error is bcoz of `price Double;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scanButton` is `null` at that point. Since you initialize it with

```
final Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
```

the problem is most likely that your layout (`current_inventory.xml`) does not have a button with id of `addButton`. (If no view with that id is found, then `findViewById` will return `null`.)

If you run the [Android lint tool](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint), it will catch errors like this.